# How can I open a specific revision of a file with Magit?

Tags: magit, git

Is it possible to open a specific revision of a file in Emacs with Magit without changing the current branch?

I have rebased some local changes to a revision where the modified functions were replaced by functionality in a different file.  I would like to open the old revision of my changes in a separate buffer so I can compare the changes side by side.

My current *hacky* solution has been to run `git show <branch pre-rebase>:file > old_file` and then open `old_file` in Emacs.

Comment: https://github.com/pidu/git-timemachine can view a file between each versions in a glance temporarily.

Comment: @kuanyui I use `git-timemachine` but since my code has been rebased I don't think it will work since the old code is not part of the current branch's history?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420282/using-emacs-and-magit-to-visit-a-file-in-given-commit-branch-etc

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can view a file for a specific revision using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `magit-find-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<filename>` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Or you can first view the diff for commit by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> on it, navigating to the file inside the diff, and then pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> again.

Comment: This works for me; here's what I do: from the current version of the file, `M-x magit-log-buffer-file`, move the line to the desired commit, then `M-x magit-find-file`. Then the default value will be that commit. I do have to give the path to the file as this is not picked up from the log buffer.

Comment: @tarsius, Somewhat like magit-find-file but where I only need to select the revision for the current buffer's file.  Does it exist already?

Comment: Yes, use `magit-find-file` itself from a file-visiting buffer and then just type `RET` at the second prompt (the proper file is offered as the default).

Comment: Thanks for the info and all all your work on Magit.  It wasn't too difficult to hack a function that skips that pesky extra keystroke, so I'm happy until the next itch occurs.

Answer (score 41):

It's possible to do with plain VC (built-in to Emacs), without Magit.  Type `C-x v ~` and type the version you want. It understands tags and SHA1 hashes, as well as the usual `~1` etc suffixes.

Comment: This is not an answer to a magit question. Would you post a C answer to a Ruby question?

Comment: @BryanAsh yes, if the solution in C is so much easier.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed, it may be off-topic but this answer certainly does the job!

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://stackoverflow.com/q/25420282