# Retrieve file from an earlier commit

Tags: magit, git

I am using Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.2.

I use magit to manage a local git repository.

In an earlier commit, there was a file. In the latest commit as well as the current working tree, the file no longer exists as it was deleted somewhere along the way.

I want to have that file from the earlier commit in the current working tree. How do I do that using magit?

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/how-can-i-open-a-specific-revision-of-a-file-with-magit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I checkout a file from another commit in Magit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14463/how-do-i-checkout-a-file-from-another-commit-in-magit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `magit-file-checkout` on the commit hash of your interest, or find the command (most likely `f file`) in `Reset` menu.

After selecting the commit hash, choose the file you wanna resurrect.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the revision where the file was deleted. You can do that with `magit-log`, then advice the full file name in "Limit to files". You will get the commit where the file was removed at the top of the log buffer.

You can open file as it was just before deleted with `magit-find-file`, settings revision to `rev^` where `rev` is the commit that delete the file. Or checkout it (`magit-file-checkout`) at the revision `rev^`.